# Determining the Old version of Visual Studio .NET project that was used to create the project

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, upgrade, backwards-compatibility

Our Customer sent us code from an Old Visual Studio .NET project
The Customer wants us to assess if it is possible to upgrade the Old Visual Studio .NET project in such that it will work in Visual Studio 2013

My first approach was to try and  run the Old Visual Studio .NET project in the corresponding Visual Studio .NET project that was used to Develop the aforementioned project at first.

please tell me how I would determine the Old version of Visual Studio .NET project that was used to create the project.

I opened the .SLN file using notepad, and the first 2 lines showed the following:

Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00

## Visual Studio 2005

What does the above mean?

Answer (score 1):

Open the `.sln` file in your favorite text editor (Notepad, if you don't have anything else will do), and check out the header:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
```

The `Format Version xx.xx` should tell you which version of Visual Studio was used.

```
Version 12.00 --> Visual Studio 2013
Version 11.00 --> Visual Studio 2012
Version 10.00 --> Visual Studio 2010
Version  9.00 --> Visual Studio 2008
```